# How to unit test service methods that are basically 1 to 1 calls to a MyBatis Mapper interface

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, mybatis

I'm new to MyBatis and Unit Testing.

I have a `CourseService` class that has (at the moment) only methods that call and return the equivalent method of the MyBatis Mapper (`CourseMapper`).

CourseService class.

```
@Autowired
private CourseMapper courseMapper;

public Course getById(int id) {
    return courseMapper.getById(id);
}
...
```

CourseMapper interface.

```
@Select("select from courses where id = #{id}")
public Course getById(int id);
...
```

Should I unit test `courseService.getById(id)`? Would be appropriate to mock the Mapper and construct the service with that mapper and make the mock call to `getById` return a Course with the id passed as argument?

```
when(courseMapper.getCourseById(anyInt()))
    .thenAnswer(this::returnCourseWithSameIdThatInTheArgument); 
...

private Course CourseWithSameIdThatInTheArgument(InvocationOnMock i) {
    return new Course((int)i.getArguments()[0],true,1,"","",1);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should mock the `CourseMapper` and verify whether `courseMapper.getById(id)` is called once with intended `id`

Something like this

> Mockito.verify(courseMapper, Mockito.times(1)).getById(id)

The reason for doing this is - CourseMapper is a different class and you can assume it is already well tested. What you are doing here is stubbing the behaviour of `CourseMapper.getById()` which is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the rule regarding verification:

**Expect certain behavior from Mocks, never from Stubs.**

As Stubs may also record behavior it is tempting to perform some verification upon them.

You need to keep in mind that they're sole purpose is to provide data for some later processing or command invocation (which are the actual features of the class under test).

Queries don't change the world so they can be called any number of times, including none.

Command calls (invoked on Mocks) on the other hand are likely to have side effects and will change the world outside of the target object.

**Your are trying to test a stub which is against that rule.**